# angularjs prevent error from bubbling to httpinterceptor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

I have an http interceptor for my angularjs app that catches any http exceptions and handles them.  There are a few cases where i would like to catch the error from the request and handle them there, preventing the error from bubbling to the interceptor.  Does anyone know how this might be possible?
Here is the interceptor:

```
angular.module('x')
    .factory('HttpErrorHandlerFactory', ['$q', '$rootScope', function ($q, $rootScope) {
        return {
            'responseError': function (rejection) {
                if (rejection.status == 0) return $q.reject(rejection);
                if (rejection.data === '')
                    rejection.data = 'Error';
                $rootScope.Message.Value = rejection.data;
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    }]);
```

This is set at the app level, so any http requests that go through are caught by this.  if they error, it catches them and displays the message.

Usually, we have calls like this:

```
  someFactory.GetSomething(scope.id)
              .success(function (result) {
                    //do something with result
               }).error(function(error){
                    //MY QUESTION IS, HOW TO GET THIS ERROR TO NOT BUBBBLE UP TO THE INTERCEPTOR
               });
```

Comment: Need to be far more specific. We don't know what interceptor is doing. Provide relevant code

Answer (score 0):

To my best knowledge you cant really prevent the interceptor from catching the error before the caller function does. indeed that is annoying.

My solution was to add a config object to specific http requests (the ones  i wanted to handle their error from the caller).

for example when using restangular:

```
  myRestangularObject.get().withHttpConfig({handleByCaller: true})
```

and on my interceptor:

```
  if (rejection.config.handleByCaller && rejection.config.handleByCaller === true) {
     return $q.reject(rejection);
  }
```

I know that this is a hack and doesn't answer your question but as i said, i don't think you can avoid the interceptor from being executed first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am not using restangular.  Any other ideas that don't use that?